# Apollo GraphiQL browser playground: How to nest queries?

Tags: graphql, subquery

Wish to run a nested query within as **Apollo GraphiQL browser playground**.

Schema for two queries intended to be nested and a response type:

```
getByMaxResults(maxResults: Int = null): [ID!]!

appById(id: ID!): AppOutputGraphType

AppOutputGraphType = {
  accountIdGuid: ID!
  createdAt: DateTime!
  description: String!
  id: ID!
  updatedAt: DateTime!
  userId: ID
}
```

Query `getByMaxResults: [ID!]!`, the result is an array of element **ID**:

[image: GraphiQL browser playground: Query getByMaxResults]

Query `appById(id: ID!)` requesting a couple of `AppOutputGraphType` fields:

[image: GraphiQL browser playground: Query appById]

Is there a way within the GraphiQL browser sandbox to nest these two Queries?:

1. query `getByMaxResults` gather an array of **IDs**.
2. Iterate this array and perform multiple queries `appById` with each **ID**.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

1. Change your definition of the `getByMaxResults` query to:

```
getByMaxResults: [AppOutputGraphType!]!
```

2. Change your resolver to return an array containing all the fields of the `AppOutputGraphType` objects and not just the `id`.
3. Then just:

```
query {
  getByMaxResults {
    id
    updatedAt
  }
}
```

There is no way in GraphQL to *nest* queries but the whole point of the language is to remove the need to do so.

With the proper resolvers you could even get the related account and user for each `AppOutputGraphType`.

Change:

```
AppOutputGraphType = {
  account: Account <= don't include foreign keys, refer to the related type
  createdAt: DateTime!
  description: String!
  id: ID!
  updatedAt: DateTime!
  user: User <= don't include foreign keys, refer to the related type
}
```

Then you can do queries like:

```
query {
  getByMaxResults {
    id
    updatedAt
    account {{
      id
      name
      city
    }
    user {
      id
      firstName
      lastName
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Also you might find my blog series on [GraphQL for SQL Developers](https://michelfloyd.hashnode.dev/graphql-for-sql-developers-part-1) useful in terms of modeling.

Comment: Michel Floyd, thank you for your response and good suggestion. Yet, I cannot change the schema for `getByMaxResults`, since it is used by many other users.

Comment: In that case create a new type with a better structure and eventually deprecate the old one. That it includes foreign keys rather than references to other types is kind of an oops.

Comment: That, too, is a great idea. Yet, I do not have permission to change the schema; it is maintained by the corporate data service. So the consideration of eventually deprecating this schema is not a possibility.

Comment: Apparently your data service team did not know much about GraphQL when they defined this schema - they basically created a REST API using POST ;) If you are being forced to do multiple queries then it's wrong.